# Is this a good method to enforce runtime type check?

Tags: c

I'm developing a GUI in c, so I have a lot of Widgets, that are basically structs, with his first member being a pointer to a base class:

```
typedef struct mkGuiButton {
    struct mkGuiWidget *base;
    int some_propperty;
    [...]
}mkGuiButton;
```

I do this way because I like the type safety at compile time this method provides, so a function like `mk_gui_button_set_label(mkGuiButton *, const char *label)` can take a `mkGuiButton *` type as parameter but not a `mkGuiText *`.

The downside of this implementations come when the function operates in some flags and properties that are common in all widgets, this is, the base struct.

I don't want to make specific functions for each widget type, so I make these functions take a `void *` pointer like this `mk_gui_set_visible(void *widget, bool state)` and then inside this function I cast the pointer to `mkGuiWidget *`, and obviously I lost type safety.

I can live without type safety at compile time, but not at runtime, so I come with this solution: the base struct, this is `mkGuiWidget`, have a special member `int signature` (int is 32 bit on my arch) that are setted to a know value when creating (like 2155553647) and then inside each "generic" function I do a check:

```
if (widget->base) {
    assert(widget->base->signature == 2155553647);
}
```

So the question is: is this a reliable method to do runtime type safety checks, or is a better method to do this?

Comment: Have you considered using C++ which already has these built in?

Comment: Sorry but C++ is not an option

Comment: Note that your check to see if it's a `mkGuiWidget *` assumes it's a `mkGuiWidget *`. The check could result in a segfault. Having `struct mkGuiWidget base` instead of `struct mkGuiWidget *base` could help avoid that.

Comment: [Type introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection) using a [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) is a well-established practice. I don't think you'll do better than that in C. (But as hinted by @ikegami, you *do* need the signature as the first element of every struct that your code uses.)

Comment: @ikegami you are completely right, and the solution is what user3386109 points. Thank you both.

Comment: I usually do type introspection more or less that way: the first member of the struct is a `uint64_t` with a per-struct-type unique value, and I define a function/macro `cast_<my_struct>(void *s)` that cast void pointer to my struct, and check if the type is right. That way, I have only two points to enable/disable type checking, and I don't have a check every function that uses my struct type.

My typical usage of this method is when I need to send this struct to a library like libev, that accepts an opaque `void *` data pointer that I will have to cast-back in callback functions.